# Do zmq subscribers know to skip subsequent parts of filtered topics for multipart messages?

Tags: zeromq

Say I have a `publisher_socket` and a `subscriber_socket`, created in two different processes. The `publisher_socket` publishes a two-part message, outlined in pseudo-code below.

```
publisher_socket.send("huge_blob", ZMQ_SNDMORE)
publisher_socket.send([ 1GB buffer of data ])
```

Suppose the`subscriber_socket` is not set up its message filter to subscribe to the topic "huge_blob". Does the associated background thread know to skip ingestion of the second part of the message? Or might I see the subscriber's memory usage shoot up to 1GB as the background thread copies the second part of the message from the network, even though it will never be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `zeromq` v3 onwards all subscriptions are filtered on the publisher side. When you subscribe on your `ZMQ_SUB` socket, the filter information is sent to the `ZMQ_PUB` socket and filtered there.

So the answer is no, you `ZMQ_SUB` process, socket, network etc will not see the first or second frame if they are not subscribed to "huge_blob"

Comment: This clarifies my mental model of topic filtering. For some reason I thought topics were filtered on subscriber side. Thanks!